# Assigning results of groupby() to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

This groupby() script:

```
df.groupby(['period', 'tier']).type.value_counts()/df.groupby(['period']).period_days.unique()
```

produces this object:

```
    period              tier      type        
first_period_1of2   10-99_cr      tup    [35]
                    100-199_cr    tup    [34]
                    200-299_cr    tup    [18]
                    300-500_cr    tup    [17]
first_period_2of2   10-99_cr      tup    [38]
                    100-199_cr    tup    [45]
                    200-299_cr    tup    [17]
                    300-500_cr    tup    [14]
second_period_1of2  30-99_cr      tup    [35]
                    100-199_cr    tup    [46]
                    200-299_cr    tup    [18]
                    300-500_cr    tup    [25]
second_period_2of2  30-99_cr      tup    [32]
                    100-199_cr    tup    [43]
                    200-299_cr    tup    [7]
                    300-500_cr    tup    [56]
dtype: object
```

I would like to apply the results of the groupby() script ([35],[34],[18]...) back to the original dataframe, in a new column, assigned to the rows where the groupby() conditions are met.

```
df.shape
(22588, 17)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
s = df.groupby(['period', 'tier']).type.value_counts()/df.groupby(['period']).period_days.unique()
df = df.join(s.rename('new'), on=['period','tier'])
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for your comment! However, I received this error message: `ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"`